# How can I clear all the records from a TDataSource?

Tags: delphi-xe

I thought this would be simple but don't see a function that clears all records from the dataset of a TDataSource.
Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of dataset? Some support that operation, some don't.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function. You have to step through all records.

```
while ds.RecordCount>0 do
  ds.delete;
```

Comment: this deletes the data from the table

Answer (score 0):

try clear the DataSet with **EmptyDataSet**..
Example... ds.EmptyDataSet;

Comment: This is only available for a `TClientDataSet`, and the poster has not indicated that a ClientDataSet is being used.